# What does the word 「なんざ」 mean?

Tags: meaning, words

What does the word 「なんざ」 mean?

> ふざけんじゃねえよ　パンチに理{り}屈{くつ}**なんざ**無{む}用{よう}だい!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

「なんざ」＝「なんぞ + は」, originally.

「～～なんぞは」⇒「～～なんざあ」⇒「～～なんざ」

The last two are heard almost exclusively around Kanto.

Meaning: Same as 「なんかは」 or 「などは」. ("Stuff like ~~", "~~ and such", etc. )

Answer (score 0):

"なんざ" is a colloquial form of "など" + "は".

Thus I would translate

> パンチに理屈なんざ無用だい

into

> No reasoning/justification is necessary for punches/fist-fighting.